# distributional derivative of characteristic function of rational numbers.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I know that the Heaviside function ($H(x) = 1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $0$ if $x<0$) has derivative $\delta_o$ on $(-1,1)$  (in sense of distribution). Now I want to find the distributional derivative of $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (characteristic function of rational numbers).

---

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}' \, \phi \,dx = - \int_{-1}^1 \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}\, \phi'\, dx
\end{equation}

Now on the right I have to integrate the characteristic function, so it is the zero function. Is it correct to say that the (distributional) derivative of $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the zero function?

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right.

Comment: Not only is this correct, but $\chi_{\mathbb Q}=0$ in $\mathcal D'$. In other words, when you interpret (locally integrable) functions as distributions, functions that agree a.e. get identified.